# Preciso pegar e exibir uma lista de objetos clientes pelo Id

Tags: c#, lista

MINHA CLASSE CLIENTEBUS

```
class ClienteBus:AplicacaoBus<Cliente>
{
    public ClienteBus()
    {
        Tabela = new List<Cliente>();
    }     
}
```

MINHA CLASSE CLIENTE

```
class Cliente:Entity
{
    private static int _Id;
    public Cliente()
    {
        _Id++;
        Id = _Id;
    }

    protected string nome;
    public string Nome
    {
        get { return nome; }
        set { nome = value; }
    }

    protected string codigo;
    public string Codigo
    {
        get { return codigo; }
        set { codigo = value; }
    }


}
```

MINHA CLASSE APLICACAOBUS

```
public class AplicacaoBus<T> where T : Entity
{
    private List<T> tabela;
    public List<T> Tabela
    {
        get { return tabela; }
        set { tabela = value; }
    }

    public void Add(T entity)
    {
        tabela.Add(entity);          
    }

    public Entity LocalizarPorId(int id)
    {

        return Tabela.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

    }
}
```

MAINWINDOW.XML.CS     NAO SEI COMO FAZER

```
private void bExibir_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var posCliente = cliBus.LocalizarPorId(cliente.Id);


        //foreach (var item in cliBus.LocalizarPorId(cliente.Id)) //percorre a collection e atribuindo a item cada valor
      //  {
      //      MessageBox.Show(item);
      //  }

    }
```

Comment: Cara, não sei se entendi muito bem o que você quer fazer, mas talvez não seria uma boa você jogar seus clientes em um HashMap e ai sim você faria a ordenação de acordo com o Id desejado.

Comment: O `posCliente` já deverá ser aquilo que voce quer